# Pickerview showing values on both sides

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipickerview

How to remove the values on the left side of the picker view? Both pickerviews are scrolling separately, it seems like the two picker views are opening side by side?

**This is how it is looking:**

[image]

**My Code:**

```
extension SignUpVC : UITextFieldDelegate {

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    
    if textField == genderTF {
    }
    return true
}}

extension SignUpVC : UIPickerViewDelegate , UIPickerViewDataSource {
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
   return genderArr.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return genderArr.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return genderArr[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
    genderTF.text = genderArr[row]
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}}
```

Comment: func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
   **return 1**
}

Comment: thank alot bro ... it worked :-)